# Import Logs from S3 to Athena using Regex

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-athena

I have exported CloudWatch logs to S3 and now want to import those logs to Athena. The format of the logs is as follow (pasted only one log for reference):

```
2021-07-30T14:30:22.937Z    RequestId   INFO    {"_logLevel":"debug","msg":"Start: Calling All the Data Associates Function","timestamp":1627655422937,"EventSubCategory":"AppSyncService","API":"AppSyncService","function":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","Correlation_Id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
```

I am using a regular expression to import the log and using the following query to create the table.

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1 (
  `time` string
  `requestid` string
  `loglevel` string
  `message` string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1',
  'input.regex' = '^(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*?)\t([\s\S]*?)\n'
)
LOCATION 's3://logs/test/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

Regular Expression:

```
^(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*?)\t([\s\S]*?)\n
```

There are four columns in the table and the regular expression is also creating four groups and working as per my expectation. However, we still get empty table as result.

Can anyone please help to resolve this issue?

Comment: I removed the duplicated timestamp at the start of the log line, because it looked like a typo (there's only one time column in the table).

Comment: It wasn't a typo error. When we export logs from CloudWatch to S3, we get two timestamps separated by space in the output file.

Comment: In that case I don't understand why your regex has four capture groups. With the start and end anchors, how would they match five columns?

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that you need to double-escape things in the regex, and you also should not match on a newline at the end, but `$`. Try this pattern:

```
'input.regex' = '^(.*?)\\t(.*?)\\t(.*?)\\t([\\s\\S]*?)$'
```

You can see an [example in the official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/regex-serde.html).

Also, the pattern `[\s\S]` could be replaced by `.` (`\S` means everything not matched by `\s`, so together they match anything).

An alternative to the regex serde is [Grok](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/grok-serde.html), which is less error prone to write. Using the Grok serde I think this table would work for you:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1 (
  `time` string
  `requestid` string
  `loglevel` string
  `message` string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.amazonaws.glue.serde.GrokSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  input.format' = '%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} %{NOTSPACE:requestid} %{NOTSPACE:loglevel} %{NOTSPACE:message}'
)
LOCATION 's3://logs/test/'
```

Grok patterns are much easier to read. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/grok-serde.html) and [the built-in patterns](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns) for more info.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks!